# Can't Deploy Wordpress with juju

Tags: juju, maas, wordpress

Successfully deployed mysql on machine 0, and forced deployment of wordpress on the same machine, i.e., `juju deploy --to 0 -repository:/xxxx local:trusty:/wordpress`. `juju status` shows installation failure:

```
wordpress/0:
    agent-state: error
    agent-state-info: 'hook failed: "install"'
    agent-version: 1.18.3.1
    machine: "0"
    public-address: node1.maas
```

Looking in `/var/log/juju/unit-mysql-0.log`, noted the following:

```
...
2014-05-20 20:39:42 INFO juju.worker.uniter modes.go:65 found queued "install" hook
2014-05-20 20:39:42 INFO juju.worker.uniter uniter.go:480 running "install" hook
2014-05-20 20:39:42 INFO install + add-apt-repository ppa:charmers/charm-helpers
2014-05-20 20:39:47 DEBUG juju.worker.uniter.filter filter.go:317 got unit change
2014-05-20 20:43:58 INFO install Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:charmers/charm-helpers'.
2014-05-20 20:43:58 INFO install Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
2014-05-20 20:43:58 ERROR juju.worker.uniter uniter.go:486 hook failed: exit status 1
2014-05-20 20:43:58 DEBUG juju.worker.uniter modes.go:384 ModeContinue exiting
...
```

Target node is a single nic machine, connected to the local maas network, and seems that it is not able to access ppa:charmers/charm-helpers. Any work around?
Cheers,

Comment: Does the machine have access to the internet to add the ppa?

Answer (score 4):

The suspected temporary fix to this is check for the presence of an apt proxy in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d and comment that out, as it causes problems with PPA installations from MAAS controlled hosts.

For example, within my maas cluster I have

`/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90curtin-aptproxy`

```
Acquire::HTTP::Proxy "http://10.0.10.2:8000/";
```

The presence of this curtin proxy causes PPA's to fail 100% of the time. Commenting it out has allowed apt to reach out through the network and install from PPA's.

Comment: It would be better to have the user setup squid-deb-proxy to properly proxy the PPA on the MAAS controller node.

Comment: LazyPower: Did the update, with no change in outcome. Do I need to reboot/restart a service. 2014-05-22 18:00:57 INFO juju.worker.uniter modes.go:382 ModeContinue starting
2014-05-22 18:00:57 INFO juju.worker.uniter modes.go:65 found queued "install" hook
2014-05-22 18:00:57 INFO juju.worker.uniter uniter.go:480 running "install" hook
2014-05-22 18:00:57 INFO install + add-apt-repository ppa:charmers/charm-helpers
2014-05-22 18:01:02 DEBUG juju.worker.uniter.filter filter.go:317 got unit change
2014-05-22 18:05:13 INFO install Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:charmers/charm-helpers'.

Comment: Unfortunately, it sounds like there's a connectivity issue between your server and the PPA. If commenting out the apt-curtain-proxy didn't resolve it. At this point we need to start peeling away the layers of complexity. When you juju ssh wordpress/0, are you able to reach the PPA using curl? (as in, do you have base line connectivity to the PPA server)

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. On the MAAS server I have full connectivity, i.e., $ curl http://ppa.launchpad.net/charmers/charm-helpers/ubuntu
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
...
<address>Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at ppa.launchpad.net Port 80</address>...
However this is not the case on the target node: ubuntu@node2:~$ curl -v http://ppa.launchpad.net/charmers/charm-helpers/ubuntu
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 91.189.95.83...

Any thoughts?

Comment: Here are some additional network data: ubuntu@node2:~$ more /etc/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 10.0.0.10
search maas
ubuntu@node2:~$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10-0-0-10.maas  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
10.0.0.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
ubuntu@node2:~$

Comment: You'll need to check your network routes. it looks like you've got connectivity to the outside world from your controller node, yet not from your cluster nodes. This is where you start to bypass my experience with MAAS - as my VMAAS setup took me a weekend to get the networking configuration perfect. (about 4 rebuilds in total since I had no idea what I was doing)